# How to install Microsoft.Build.CopyOnWrite into Visual Studio projects for optimizing a DevDrive?

Tags: .net

The `Microsoft.Build.CopyOnWrite` [package](https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildSdks/blob/main/src/CopyOnWrite/README.md) is required at this point in time to enable CopyOnWrite linking in build tools. Specifically for the ReFS filesystem with a [DevDrive in Windows 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-drive/).

##### TLDR; how do I install it?

I can't make any sense of the ReadMe docs which don't really explain how to install it. Perhaps it's as simple as just adding it to every project in my solution but it's not clear and I don't want to blindly do that and have no clue if it worked.

The [README](https://github.com/microsoft/MSBuildSdks/blob/main/src/CopyOnWrite/README.md) has a section on `Usage in Directory.Packages.Props`, but I've never even heard of such a thing.

- How do I install it in a Visual Studio .NET framework project and/or .NET Core project
- Does it need to be added to all projects? Do I need to do anything else or just add it with nuget?
- How do I know it's actually working?

Eventually it seems it [won't be required](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2023/10/25/announcing-windows-11-insider-preview-build-25982-canary-channel/), but I'm not on the Canary channel. At that point in time I assume I'll just be able to uninstall it.